# Missing right parenthesis after (or before) default 0, Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-sql-developer, default-value

I am trying to create a table with Oracle SQL where two columns of the table should have a default value and should not be NULL.

I am getting the error you can see below, but i am not able to understand it, because the are no parenthesis to be closed there!

## The Script

```
 CREATE TABLE ENCUENTROS (
  elocal constraint clave_extrana_equipos references equipos(code) not null enable,
  evisitante constraint clave_extrana_equipos references equipos(code) not null enable,
  fecha date,
  plocal number constraint plocal_mayor_cero check (plocal > 0) default 0 not null enable,
  pvisitante number constraint pvisitante_mayor_cero check (pvisitante > 0) default 0 not null enable);
```

## The Error Message

> ```
> plocal number constraint plocal_mayor_cero check (plocal > 0) default 0 not null enable,
>                                                               *
> ERROR at line 5:
> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
> ```

<sup>* is where Oracle detected the error</sup>

I'm at loss as to why there should be an error at that position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the ordering of the clauses. If you move the `CHECK` constraint **after** the `DEFAULT 0` clause, then the table creates:

```
CREATE TABLE ENCUENTROS (
  elocal constraint clave_extrana_equipos_1 references equipos(code) not null enable,
  evisitante constraint clave_extrana_equipos_2 references equipos(code) not null enable,
  fecha date,
  plocal number default 0 not null enable constraint plocal_mayor_cero check (plocal > 0),
  pvisitante number default 0 not null enable constraint pvisitante_mayor_cero check (pvisitante > 0)
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE ENCUENTROS (
  elocal constraint clave_extrana_equipos_1 references equipos(code) not null enable,
  evisitante constraint clave_extrana_equipos_2 references equipos(code) not null enable,
  fecha date,
  plocal number default 0 constraint plocal_mayor_cero check (plocal > 0) not null enable,
  pvisitante number default 0 constraint pvisitante_mayor_cero check (pvisitante > 0) not null enable 
);
```

Note that I had to give different names to the two foreign key constraints.

BTW, there is a bit of a oddity in your definition: you require a value for `local` and `pvisitante` and if none is passed, then you use `0`. But the check contraint requires the value to be `>0`. Meaning that any insert that does not provide a value will fail ... The error will be something like `constraint pvisitante_mayor_cero failed validation` or similar.

Maybe a simpler approach would be to remove the `default` clause. This will then make an insert that does not include `pvisitante` fail with a different error: `cannot insert null into ENCUENTROS (PVISITANTE)`. That may be clearer to application developers.